# Organize registering Vue global components in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

In Vue 2 you can globally register components over multiple files by using the following code in **index.js** without bloating the **main.js** file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent'

Vue.component('my-component-name', MyComponent)
```

And in the **main.js** file use

```
import '@/components'
```

---

But this method doesn't seem to work for me in Vue 3

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import '@/components'

const app = createApp({});

app.mount("#app");
```

**index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue' // doesn't work with import { createApp } from 'vue' too
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent'

Vue.component('my-component-name', MyComponent)
```

How can you achieve the same result in Vue 3?

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/global-api.html#share-configurations-among-apps

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was stumbling upon the same issue. To still have my components in an external file, I made my `registerComponents.ts` as a component loader function that as an argument receives the vue app it should add the components to.

So in my case I have a file `registerComponents.ts` that looks like this

```js
import { App } from "vue";

// import components
import button from '@/components/Button.vue';

// register components
export const registerComponents = (app: App): void => {
    app.component('tw-button', button);
}
```

and my `main.ts` then uses the function before mounting:

```js
const app = createApp(App)
    .use(store)
    .use(router)
    .use(i18n);

registerComponents(app);

app.mount("#app");
```

Maybe this helps somebody :-)

Answer (score 4):

There is no global registration in Vue 3. Everything is scoped to a particular app.

So the closest you can get is:

```js
const app = createApp({});

app.component('my-component-name', MyComponent)

app.mount("#app");
```

You will have to decide the best way to pass the relevant bits between your two files. For example, you might make `index.js` a plugin.

RFC: https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0009-global-api-change.md

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3 we can have [multiple application instances](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#multiple-application-instances)

```js
const app1 = createApp({})
app1.mount('#container-1')

const app2 = createApp({})
app2.mount('#container-2')
```

that can co-exist on that same page. So we can no longer use `Vue` from `import Vue from 'vue'` to register/use plugins.

---

## My solution

> [See the implementation live on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-qqpgvq?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/main.js)

#### Step 1: Create a folder to keep plugins/packages/dependencies

I've called it `plugins` since they will be plugged in `main.js`.

#### Step 2: Create `main-app.js`

You can also call it `app1.js` or whatever you want. Here is the content:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from '../App.vue'

export const app = createApp(App)
```

#### Step 3: Plug it in `main.js`

```js
import { app } from './plugins/main-app'

app.mount('#app')
```

#### Step 4: Create a new plugin

Now let's create a `src/plugins/global-components.js`

```js
import { app } from './main-app'
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent'

app.component('my-component-name', MyComponent)
```

Register it in `main.js`:

```js
import { app } from './plugins/main-app'
import './plugins/global-components'

app.mount('#app')
```

*You can go a step further and have an `index.js` in `src/plugins` where it will be like `main.js` and then in `main.js` you simply have `import './plugins'` but personally I don't like this extra step*