# How to pass createApp in Vue 3 among the app?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm migrating from Vue 2 to Vue 3. In Vue 2, it's possible to register a component globally like this: **main.js**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

A global registration of a component: **my-component.js**

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<div>Hi!</div>'
})
```

I'm using Webpack for import Single File Components in other components, and then i'm bundling it in one file. With Vue 2, that was easy because Vue instance was globally registered. Now with Vue 3, that doesn't work any more because of  `Vue.createApp({}).mount('#app')`. I was trying to do something like this: **main.js**

```js
const app = createApp({});

export const app;
```

And in: **my-component.js**

```js
import { app } from './main.js';

app.component('my-component', {
  template: '<div>Hi!</div>'
})
```

And at the end: **close-app.js**

```js
import { app } from './main.js';

app.mount('#app');
```

And in: **index.html**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.5/vue.global.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="my-component.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <my-component></my-component>
</div>
<script type="application/javascript" src="close-app.js"></script>
```

I'm importing the `app` because of Webpack. Webpack is bundling it in self-invoking functions, but that doesn't work. I know there is a way to declare it globally like this: `window.app = app;`, but that's not a good idea. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: why don't you use single file components with .vue extension?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim i'm using that as SFC as i wrote. I'm importing those SFC  into other components and i'm bundling them with webpack.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't use SFC

Comment: @Daniel_Knights yes because that's not relevant for my question but i wrote: "I'm using Webpack for import Single File Components in other components, and then i'm bundling it in one file".

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71108589/6385184

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Components Webpacks

Since Vue 3 component registration has to be invoked on an app instance, and you're importing each component Webpack individually, I don't think you can avoid globals. Using a global `app` instance (`window.app`) in your components might be the easiest solution, especially if you want to minimize the changes.

Alternatively, you could build the components as UMD modules, where the component definition is exported as a global, import the UMD module with the `<script>` tag (as you're already doing), and call `app.component()` for each of them:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.5/vue.global.js"></script>

<!-- sets MyComponent global -->
<script type="application/javascript" src="./my-component.umd.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>

<script>
const app = Vue.createApp({})
app.component(MyComponent.name, MyComponent)
app.mount('#app')
</script>
```

#### Component Module Scripts

In `main.js`, use `createApp` from the global `Vue` that you've imported in the `<script>` tag:

```js
export const app = Vue.createApp({})
```

Then import your scripts as modules with `<script type="module">`:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.5/vue.global.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="./my-component.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
<script type="module" src="./close-app.js"></script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/partial-init-with-vue-3-from-cdn-65oro?file=/index.html)

Comment: i was using ```application/javascript``` because at the end i have a bundle file from webpack and that don't need ````module``` (i can't provide you those files in codesandbox).  Your answer is correct but thats doesn't solve my problem. I think the problem is webpack? But i need webpack because i'm importing e.g. in ```<my-component></my-component>``` other SFC. Is there any way to reach that also with export and inport of ```app``` in webpack? If you don't have any ideas that i will accept you answer to becuase thats is correct. But if you have any ideas then please let me know.

Comment: @CananauCristian I don't think you can avoid globals for this scenario. However, it's common for UMD libs to export component definitions that an app instance registers (see update in answer), so you might consider that design instead.