# how to get app instance for register component or plugin globally in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

i have a two layout admin and user
I want to register some specific component to register to admin layout
how can I register components from adminlayout.vue

Answer (score 0):

You can register and use the component globally by importing the component into your `main.ts` file and [registering it](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html) using `app.component`:

```js
// main.ts
import App from "@/App.vue";
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue'

const app = createApp(App);
app.component("ChildComponent", ChildComponent);

app.mount("#app");
```

You can also do the same from a parent component.

If you're using the [Composition API](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html) with `<script setup>`:

```js
// Parent.vue
<script setup>
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <h1>Here is a child component!</h1>
  <ChildComponent />
</template>
```

Comment: i dont want to use admin layout component to user layout

Comment: I don't understand your question then. Please edit it to make it more clear, and preferably include some code examples.

Comment: i have two layout call admin layout and user layout. I want to register some component to admin layout for admin layout child component use those are component which are register component

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want to do. Maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63261636/organize-registering-vue-global-components-in-vue-3